# How to process list and then clear list, while unpacking data into dataframe to free memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, memory-management

I am calling xml data from an api and appending the data into a list. I have to make roughly ~300K api calls which I think is causing my application to crash because when I am appending into the list, there is too much data.

Below is code to call api and save results into list. `lst1` is a list of ids that I pass into the api. I have to take into account that if the http request times out or I can build a mechanism to clear the appended list of data, that I can restart the requests from the ID I left off at from `lst1` which is passed into the api url.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import time
from concurrent import futures

lst1=[1,2,3]

lst =[]

for i in lst1:
    url = 'urlId={}'.format(i)
    while True:
        try:
            xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
            print(xml_data1)
            break
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(e)
    lst.append(xml_data1)
```

I am thinking that if I can apply my below function to unpack the xml into a dataframe and perform the needed dataframe manipulation, while clearing the list of appended data `lst` that it could free memory. IF this is not the case, I am open to any suggestions to allowing code or application to not crash with what I believe is too much xml data in the list:

```
def create_dataframe(xml):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")
    # Get Attributes from all nodes
    attrs = []
    for elm in soup():  # soup() is equivalent to soup.find_all()
        attrs.append(elm.attrs)
    # Since you want the data in a dataframe, it makes sense for each field to be a new row consisting of all the other node attributes
    fields_attribute_list = [x for x in attrs if 'Id' in x.keys()]
    other_attribute_list = [x for x in attrs if 'Id' not in x.keys() and x != {}]
    # Make a single dictionary with the attributes of all nodes except for the `Field` nodes.
    attribute_dict = {}
    for d in other_attribute_list:
        for k, v in d.items():
            attribute_dict.setdefault(k, v)
    # Update each field row with attributes from all other nodes.
    full_list = []
    for field in fields_attribute_list:
        field.update(attribute_dict)
        full_list.append(field)
    # Make Dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(full_list)
    return df


with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:  # Or use ProcessPoolExecutor
    df_list = executor.map(create_dataframe, lst)

full_df = pd.concat(df_list)
print(full_df)


#final pivoted dataframe
final_df = pd.pivot_table(full_df, index='Id', columns='FieldTitle', values='Value', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```